# How to get all 'first' instances of grouped and recurring values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe (1.5mln,13) and I want to retrieve the index of all the first occurences of grouped events.

The events are repeating in groups of varying lenghts like in my example date.

How can I get a list with all the first 'a' events, and all the first 'b' events?

Example data:

```
data = {'event':  ['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','a','a','a','b','b','b','b']}
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['event'])
```

Comment: what's the desired output?. (a,0), (b,5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood, you want the first row from
a sequence of consecutive rows with the same value
in *event* column.

The code to get this result is:

```
df[df.event != df.event.shift()]
```

(compare the current value with the previous, looking for "different"
cases, then use this intermediate result in *boolean indexing*).

For your data sample the result is:

```
   event
0      a
5      b
9      a
12     b
17     a
20     b
```